# kind-projector returns strange results

Tags: scala, functional-programming, higher-kinded-types, partial-application, kind-projector

I have these types:
`SomeTypeClass` 
A higher kinded type which has one type parameter of kind * => * => *

```
trait SomeTypeClass[P[_, _]] {
    def test[F[_], S, T, A, B](f: (A => F[B]) => S => F[T])
                              (pab: P[A, B])
                              (implicit ev: Strong[P],
                              ev2: Choice[P],
                              ev3: Applicative[F]): P[S, T]
}
```

`Target` which accepts three type parameters:
 type constructor `F[_]` and two polymorphic types `A, B`

```
case class Target[F[_], A, B](f: A => F[B])
```

I want to implement an instance of SomeTypeClass of Target.
I am using the kind-projector plugin in order to create a partially applied type.
My desired method signature should be:

```
implicit def instance: SomeTypeClass[Target[F, *, *]] = new SomeTypeClass[Target[F, *, *]] {
  override def test[F[_], S, T, A, B](f: (A => F[B]) => S => F[T])
                                      (pab: Target[F, A, B])
                                      (implicit ev: Strong[Target[F, *, *]], 
                                       ev2: Choice[Target[F, *, *]], 
                                       ev3: Applicative[F]): Target[F, S, T] = ???
}
```

I've tried using this syntax using two star parameters:

```
 implicit def instance[F[_]]: SomeTypeClass[Target[F, *, *]] = new SomeTypeClass[Target[F, *, *]] {
    override def test[F[_], S, T, A, B](f: (A => F[B]) => S => F[T])
                                     (pab: Target[F, A, B])
                                     (implicit ev: Strong[Target[F, *, *]],
                                      ev2: Choice[Target[F, *, *]],
                                      ev3: Applicative[F]): Target[F, S, T] = ???
}
```

But the `F[_]` declared at the instance level shadows the `F[_]` declared at the test method (I want them to be the same F), so I've moved to the λ syntax and got two different unwanted results.

The first one using `λ[(F, A, B) => Target[F, A, B]]` generated for the `pab` paramter,
`pab: Target[A, B, B]` instead of `pab: Target[F, A, B]` and also for the return type `Target[S, T, B]` instead of `Target[F, S, T]`

The second one using the F at the end of the triple type lambda parameters (why???)
 `λ[(A, B, F) => Target[F, A, B]]` generated the correct types for the `pab` parameter and the return type, but 
for each one of the implicit parameters the type `Strong[λ[(A, B, F) => Target[F, A, B]]]` instead of 
`Strong[Target[F, *, *]]]`

The full code:

```
  import cats.Applicative
  import cats.arrow.{Choice, Strong}

  final case class Target[F[_], A, B](f: A => F[B])

  trait SomeTypeClass[P[_, _]] {
    def test[F[_], S, T, A, B](f: (A => F[B]) => S => F[T])
                              (pab: P[A, B])
                              (implicit ev: Strong[P],
                               ev2: Choice[P],
                               ev3: Applicative[F]): P[S, T]
  }

  object SomeTypeClass {
    implicit def instance1: SomeTypeClass[λ[(F, A, B) => Target[F, A, B]]] = new SomeTypeClass[λ[(F, A, B) => Target[F, A, B]]] {
      override def test[F[_], S, T, A, B](f: (A => F[B]) => S => F[T])
                                         (pab: Target[A, B, B])
                                         (implicit ev: Strong[Target],
                                          ev2: Choice[Target],
                                          ev3: Applicative[F]): Target[S, T, B] = ???
    }

    implicit def instance2: SomeTypeClass[λ[(A, B, F) => Target[F, A, B]]] = new SomeTypeClass[λ[(A, B, F) => Target[F, A, B]]] {
      override def test[F[_], S, T, A, B](f: (A => F[B]) => S => F[T])
                                         (pab: Target[F, A, B])
                                         (implicit ev: Strong[λ[(A, B, F) => Target[F, A, B]]],
                                          ev2: Choice[λ[(A, B, F) => Target[F, A, B]]],
                                          ev3: Applicative[F]): Target[F, S, T] = ???
    }
  }
```

Can I achieve the desired syntax using this plugin?
 Why does the plugin generate different types 
for different order of type lambda's 'parameters'?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by these uses of `λ` "generating the correct types" for the parameter. Neither of these compile, and I wouldn't expect either to. If you want to use a type lambda in the context of `SomeClass[...]` you'll definitely need one with two `*` parameters.

Comment: @TravisBrown, I've updated the question with the two star parameters example

Comment: But `λ[(F, A, B) => Target[F, A, B]]` takes three parameters, so you definitely shouldn't be able to use it in any context where a `P[_, _]` is expected. If your final code block compiles at all that's a bug.

Comment: @TravisBrown I've also tried λ[F[_] => Target[F, *, *]]  but I also got unwanted results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood

> But the `F[_]` declared at the instance level shadows the `F[_]` declared at the test method (I want them to be the same `F`)

correctly, you want your instance for `SomeTypeClass[Target[...]]` to fix the `F[_]` parameter of `test`. But that's simply not possible with this `test` type signature. Once you have (for example)

```
val inst = implicitly[SomeTypeClass[Target[...]]
```

you can call

```
val res1 = inst.test[List, ...]
val res2 = inst.test[Option, ...]
```

Type lambdas don't offer a way around this problem. You need to either move `F[_]` parameter to `SomeTypeClass` or implement

```
implicit def instance[F[_]]: SomeTypeClass[Target[F, *, *]] = new SomeTypeClass[Target[F, *, *]] {
  override def test[G[_], S, T, A, B](f: (A => G[B]) => S => G[T])
                                     (pab: Target[F, A, B])
                                     (implicit ev: Strong[Target[F, *, *]],
                                      ev2: Choice[Target[F, *, *]],
                                      ev3: Applicative[G]): Target[G, S, T] = ???
}
```

which I expect is impossible as you can't pass `pab.f` to `f`.

EDIT: the type of `wander`

```
class (Choice p, Strong p) => Traversing p where
  traverse' :: Traversable f => p a b -> p (f a) (f b)
  traverse' = wander traverse

  wander :: (forall f. Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t) -> p a b -> p s t
  wander f pab = dimap (\s -> Baz $ \afb -> f afb s) sold (traverse' pab)
```

is a [rank-2 type](https://ocharles.org.uk/guest-posts/2014-12-18-rank-n-types.html) which aren't supported in Scala directly; instead you need to introduce a helper (which can't just be a type alias [as it is in `Control.Lens.Type`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tweak-0.1.0.1/docs/Control-Lens-Type.html#t:Traversal))

```
trait Traversal[S, T, A, B] {
  def apply[F[_]: Applicative](f: A => F[B]): S => F[T]
}
```

Then

```
trait Traversing[P[_, _]] extends Strong[P] with Choice[P] {
  def wander[S, T, A, B](t: Traversal[S, T, A, B], pab: P[A, B]): P[S, T]
}

implicit def instance[F[_]: Applicative]: Traversing[Target[F, *, *]] = new Traversing[Target[F, *, *]] {
  def wander[S, T, A, B](t: Traversal[S, T, A, B], pab: Target[F, A, B]): Target[F, S, T] = Target(t(pab.f))
  // define Strong and Choice methods too
}
```

should work. (Though I am not sure this is the cats way to deal with `Strong` and `Choice` requirements.)

Comment: So basically I can not implement this? instance testSomeTypeClass :: Applicative f => SomeTypeClass (Target f) where
  test t (Target f) = Target  (t f)

Comment: What does your `SomeTypeClass` (type of `test` in particular) look like in Haskell?

Comment: Looks like a lens

Comment: test:: Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t -> p a b -> p s t

Comment: Then you have shadowing in Haskell as well, `f` in `test` is unrelated to `f` in `instance Applicative f => SomeTypeClass (Target f)` (assuming `class SomeTypeClass p where test :: ...` and not `SomeTypeClass p f`). So `test t (Target f) = Target (t f)` shouldn't type-check, unless I am missing something.

Comment: And this doesn't compile if I try it, as expected: "Couldn't match expected type ‘f t
 -> Target m a b -> Target m s t’ with actual type ‘Target f0 a1 b0’" in `wander f (Target amb) = Target (f amb)`.

Comment: Though this `wander` corresponds to `def test[F[_], S, T, A, B](f: A => F[B])(x: S, y: F[T], pab: P[A, B])(implicit ...): P[S, T]` in Scala, not the signature you have in the question.

Comment: can you please write down the typeclass of Traversing (just the wander) which corresponds to SomeTypeClass and the signature of Star which corresponds to Target from this Haskell implementation: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/profunctors-5.5.1/docs/src/Data.Profunctor.Traversing.html#Traversing. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much, I wish I could upvote your answer more than one time

Comment: Sure did. Even before you have edited your answer with the Traversal. Just for the effort you showed. Thanks Again

Comment: @Sagi No, you haven't yet. Accepting is separate from upvoting, you need to click on a checkmark under the answer. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work